# Why in the world was this automatically bumped?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://serverfault.com/questions/160500/any-web-email-providers-that-support-sending-and-receiving-s-mime-encrypted-emai) was apparently automatically bumped to the front page. But the last activity it received was back in 2010.

Furthermore, its off topic. How has it survived for this long? But more importantly, why was it bumped?

Comment: Perhaps it's because of "Community"'s current reputation: Community♦ 666. Oh no, we're doomed!

Comment: I always knew there was something satanical about that user...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It was poked because it is "un-answered" (no accepted answer, all answers have 0 votes). Community randomly pokes these old questions to bring them to our attention.

Comment: Yup. [What can cause my question to be bumped?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48579/142484)

Comment: And one advantage of that is we get to close some of this old crap, which would otherwise remain hidden.